# inversify typescript factory binding returns union type?

Tags: typescript, inversifyjs

I'm using inversify v4.13.0 and Typescript, both of which I'm new to.

I have a `Logger` interface:

```
interface Logger {
  log(level: string, message: string, meta?: any): void;
}
```

a TYPES file:

```
const TYPES = {
  Config: Symbol.for('Config'),
  LoggerFactory: Symbol.for('Factory<Logger>')
};
```

and some bindings, including my problematic logger factory binding that also takes a config object as a parameter:

```
referenceContainer.bind<Config>(TYPES.Config).to(Config);

referenceContainer.bind<interfaces.Factory<Logger>>(TYPES.LoggerFactory).toFactory<Logger>(
  (context: interfaces.Context) => {
    return (options: PrefixedLoggerOptions = {}): Logger => {
      // return an object that implements Logger
      return PrefixedLoggerFactory(options);
    };
  });
```

Then I try to use my logger:

```
async function runApp() {
  const config = referenceContainer.get<Config>(TYPES.Config);
  const logger = referenceContainer.get<interfaces.Factory<Logger>>(TYPES.LoggerFactory)(config.loggerOptions);

  // **** error: logger has no 'log' property ****
  logger.log('info', 'am I a logger? nope!');

  // but this works
  (logger as Logger).log('info', 'am I a logger? yep!');
}

(async () => {
  await runApp();
})();
```

I see this error if I try to use the Logger without casting:

```
error TS2339: Property 'log' does not exist on type 'Logger | ((...args: any[]) => Logger)'.
Property 'log' does not exist on type '(...args: any[]) => Logger'.
```

The factory seems to be returning a unioned returned type of itself -- the factory function (strange???) and the Logger.

I checked the typedefs and this even seems to be correct although I don't understand how this could work. From the typedefs:

```
type Factory<T> = (...args: any[]) => (((...args: any[]) => T) | T);
```

Am I using inversify for factories incorrectly? How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a guess as to why this was implemented this way - to allow currying twice while binding. If Factory is not a union type you would not be able to bind something like:

```
context => (options) => (destination) => { ...destination based logger... }
```

However, as you just noted, you may cast it to your required type, if you are sure that your factory is not going to return a closure. And you could do that while assigning as well:

```
const logger: Logger = referenceContainer.get<interfaces.Factory<Logger>>(TYPES.LoggerFactory)(config.loggerOptions) as Logger;
```

Also it is a good idea to use `@inject` decorator wherever possible. I think since this is the `runApp` function which is like an entry point it is ok to use it. But otherwise, for good decoupling and testability we should use the decorator.